# Concatenating R strings with a separator - except the first time

Tags: r, string

I have a process that does a few checks to a data frame, and at each check if the check passes I want to add a text to a column with a separator. So suppose after the first test rows 2 and 3 pass, so the `msg` column has "first" in it. Then the second test updated the `ok` column and is true for rows 1 and 2, giving the following:

```
> d = data.frame(ok=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE), msg=c("", "first","first",""))
> d
     ok   msg
1  TRUE      
2  TRUE first
3 FALSE first
4 FALSE
```

so the next step would be to add "second" to the `msg` column in rows 1 and 2 only, resulting in:

```
     ok          msg
1  TRUE       second
2  TRUE first;second
3 FALSE        first
4 FALSE
```

I can't work out how to do it. This first effort leaves a leading separator in the initial case:

```
> paste(d$msg[d$ok],"second", sep=";")
[1] ";second"      "first;second"
```

This returns a length-3 vector which is clearly wrong:

```
> paste(c(d$msg[d$ok],"second"), sep=";")
[1] ""       "first"  "second"
```

and anything with `collapse` returns a length-1 vector which is also wrong.

Sledgehammer solution is to use the first effort above and then strip any leading separators at the end, but that's ugly. I'm hoping for something neater.

Solutions should only use **base R functions**, and the initial "empty string" doesn't have to be `""` - but I've played with `NA` and got nowhere. A solution neater (in my opinion) than my sledgehammer will get accepted.

Comment: Maybe add new columns for each test, then apply(df[flag_cols], 1, function(x) paste(x[nzchar(x)], collapse=';'))?

Comment: Maybe regex can be helpful like  `out <- paste(d$msg[d$ok],"second", sep=";")` and  `gsub('^\\;|\\.$', '', out)`. Or in a combined version `gsub('^\\;|\\.$', '',  paste(d$msg[d$ok],"second",sep=";"))`

Comment: @maydin that's my sledgehammer, except I use `sub` instead of `gsub` and it will strip the first separator instance, and I can ensure there's always a first separator instance.

Comment: Ops.. I did not read the entire text. Sorry.

Comment: Maybe `sapply(d$msg[d$ok], function(x) (paste(c(x[nchar(x)>0], "second"), collapse=";")))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Using your dataframe `d`, we can use a base `ifelse` function to get around your problems with separators:

```
d$msg <- as.character(d$msg)

d$msg[d$ok] <- ifelse(d$msg[d$ok] == "", "second", paste(d$msg[d$ok], "second", sep=";"))
```

Output:

```
     ok          msg
1  TRUE       second
2  TRUE first;second
3 FALSE        first
4 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which tests the cases of an empty string:

```
strAppend <- function(a, b, sep=";") {
  paste0(a, c("", sep)[1+nchar(a)>0], b)
#  paste0(a, c(sep,"")[1+(a=="")], b)    #Alternative
}

strAppend(d$msg[d$ok], "second")
#[1] "second"       "first;second"
```